# Rotating Body Vs Rigid Body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, orbital-motion

My Text Book says:

> ***On a rotating body***

,points that are at different distances from the axis

> do *not have same speed or acceleration*

, but all points ***on a rigid body*** rotating about a fixed axis do have the same angular displacement,angular speed and and angular acceleration at any instant.
                        I could not understand this statement,
**1**.when the writer says on a rotating body,what does he mean?(a rotating irregular body or something else)  and 
**2**.when he says same speed or acceleration ;does he  mean to say same angular speed and acceleration or same linear speed or acceleration?

Answer (score 1):

If this is an introductory classical mechanics text, one can assume that in both cases he is talking about a solid. Rigid body means solid. It's rigid because it's not deforming, the points that belong to it are not moving respective to each other. Rotating body can be either a solid or a deformable body. By rotating body, he likely also means a solid, because deformable bodies are only studied after a great deal of rigid body mechanics.

A solid rotates around a particular axis in space. The angular velocity and accelerations are the same for the whole solid, and they are defined in a such a way that one speaks of the "angular velocity of the solid". One can extend this definition to the points of the solid, saying that these all have the same angular velocity rotating around the solid's axis of rotation.

However, the linear velocity of points in a solid is a very different thing. Look up the velocity field for a solid body rotation. Imagine two concentric circumferences, and points on the same radius moving along them. If the angle advances at a constant rate, given a certain time, the point on the circumference with the longest radius will have travelled a greater distance. This is something that is obvious from the geometry of circumferences, given a certain angle, the greater the radius, the longer the arc will be. The arc being the length of the circumference between the two radii. Since both points have travelled the same angle in the same time, but the external one has travelled a greater distance, it's clear that its velocity is greater.

You can see this for yourself rotating any object around you. Your rotation will give it a constant angular velocity. You'll see that the points that are radially farthest from the axis of rotation will be going faster, and ones closer will be going slower. The angular velocity is the same for all points, because that is how fast you are rotating the object.

Answer (score 0):

For any rotating body (regular or irregular), it is in general true that points that are a different distance from the axis will have different linear speed and acceleration; but if the body is *rigid*, then all points will have the same angular velocity and angular acceleration. So

1. the writer means "any" body
2. the writer means "same angular speed and same angular acceleration" (which is actually verbatim in the quote you gave).